# Docker on Windows 11 and WSL2 super slow with wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, docker, wsl-2

Fresh install of windows 11 and docker. i7 and 16GB. I am developing a wordpress site. The wordpresssite is super slow when running with docker. Opening a page takes like 10 seconds.

I already tried creating a .wslconfig file with the following content

```
[wsl2] 
memory=6000MB    #Limits VM memory in WSL 2 to 6000MB 
processors=4    #Makes the WSL 2 VM use four virtual processors
```

Same result, although vmmem now uses less memory. Super slow.

What else can I do?

Would turning WSL2 off be helpful? Shouldn't WSL2 be better performance?

Comment: I turned off WSL2 and my wordpress docker site became very fast. I have another non-wordpress php site and that one became fast as well.